AI Calltaker with Twilio, Ngrok, AssemblyAI and OpenAI
I'm working on a system that uses Twilio to handle incoming voice calls, AssemblyAI to transcribe them, and OpenAI dynamically respond based on the conversation. My goal is to be able to update messages in real-time during a live call and send the updated messages to the caller without interrupting the call.
I'm using Flask to manage HTTP requests and WebSocket connections for real-time updates. Additionally, I'm using ngrok to expose my local Flask app to Twilio's webhooks.
What’s currently working:
I can successfully receive calls, transcribe them, and send an initial message to the caller.
WebSocket connections are established, and I'm able to receive transcription data and process it.
ngrok is correctly exposing my local server, and Twilio can communicate with it.
The Problem can be solved by pressing digits during the call, after which the response can be heard. But I'm not able to simulate the event of sending a "fictional" digit press at the right time.
What’s not working:
During the live call, I'm not able to dynamically update and send new messages to the caller when the content of the message changes. The first message is sent, but subsequent message updates are not being communicated to the caller in real-time.
I’m looking for a mechanism to detect changes in my dynamic message and trigger a real-time update during the call, either using WebSockets or via the Twilio API.
Main.py:
import base64
import json
import os
import time

from twilio.twiml.voice_response import VoiceResponse, Say, Start, Stream, Gather
from flask import Flask, request, Response
from flask_sock import Sock
import ngrok
from twilio.rest import Client
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from twilio_transcriber import get_assistant_message

# from utilities import checkforupdate
load_dotenv()

from twilio_transcriber import TwilioTranscriber

# Flask settings
PORT = 5001
DEBUG = False
INCOMING_CALL_ROUTE = '/'
WEBSOCKET_ROUTE = '/realtime'

# Twilio authentication
account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
api_key = os.environ['TWILIO_API_KEY_SID']
api_secret = os.environ['TWILIO_API_SECRET']
client = Client(api_key, api_secret, account_sid)

# Twilio phone number to call
TWILIO_NUMBER = os.environ['TWILIO_NUMBER']

# ngrok authentication
ngrok.set_auth_token(os.getenv("NGROK_AUTHTOKEN"))
app = Flask(__name__)
sock = Sock(app)

# Dynamically fetch the assistant message from twilio_transcriber
checkforupdate = get_assistant_message()

oldmessage = ""

dynamic_message = "Emergency center, where is the incident location?"

connected_websockets = []  # To keep track of connected websocket clients


def process_message_update():
    """
    Diese Funktion prüft, ob sich die Nachricht geändert hat und gibt die entsprechende Aktion zurück.
    """
    global dynamic_message
    global oldmessage

    # Fetch the updated assistant message
    dynamic_message = get_assistant_message()

    if dynamic_message == oldmessage:
        print("No change in message, pausing")
        return None
    else:
        print(f"New message: {dynamic_message}")
        oldmessage = dynamic_message  # Update old message to the current one
        return dynamic_message

@app.route(INCOMING_CALL_ROUTE, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def receive_call():
    global dynamic_message
    global oldmessage

    response = VoiceResponse()
    start = Start()
    start.stream(url=f'wss://{request.host}{WEBSOCKET_ROUTE}')
    response.append(start)

    # Use the updated message logic here
    message_to_say = process_message_update()

    if message_to_say:
        response.say(f"{message_to_say}", voice="man", language="US")

    # Optionally, gather input from the user between messages
    gather = Gather(input="dtmf", timeout=20, num_digits=1)
    response.append(gather)

    user_input = request.form.get('Digits', '')

    if user_input:
        response.say(f"You pressed {user_input}. Moving on.")

    return str(response)


@sock.route(WEBSOCKET_ROUTE)
def transcription_websocket(ws):
    connected_websockets.append(ws)

    transcriber = TwilioTranscriber()
    transcriber.connect()
    print('Transcriber connected')

    try:
        while True:
            data = json.loads(ws.receive())
            match data['event']:
                case "connected":
                    print('Transcriber started')
                case "start":
                    print('Twilio started')
                case "media":
                    payload_b64 = data['media']['payload']
                    payload_mulaw = base64.b64decode(payload_b64)
                    transcriber.stream(payload_mulaw)
                case "stop":
                    print('Twilio stopped')
                    transcriber.close()
                    print('Transcriber closed')
                case "say_message":
                    message = data['message']
                    print(f"Say message received: {message}")
                    say_xml = f"""
<Response>
    <Say voice="man" language="US">
        {message}
    </Say>
</Response>
""".strip()

                    for ws in connected_websockets:
                        ws.send(json.dumps({
                            "event": "send_say_response",
                            "response": say_xml
                        }))
    finally:
        connected_websockets.remove(ws)


@app.route('/update_message_v2', methods=['POST'])
def update_message_v2():
    data = request.json
    message = data['message']
    print(f"Nachricht aktualisiert: {message}")

    # Inform WebSocket clients of the message update
    for ws in connected_websockets:
        ws.send(json.dumps({
            "event": "say_message",
            "message": message
        }))

    return Response(status=200)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        # Open Ngrok tunnel
        listener = ngrok.forward(f"http://localhost:{PORT}")
        print(f"Ngrok tunnel opened at {listener.url()} for port {PORT}")
        NGROK_URL = listener.url()

        # Set ngrok URL to be the webhook for the appropriate Twilio number
        twilio_numbers = client.incoming_phone_numbers.list()
        twilio_number_sid = [num.sid for num in twilio_numbers if num.phone_number == TWILIO_NUMBER][0]
        client.incoming_phone_numbers(twilio_number_sid).update(voice_url=f"{NGROK_URL}{INCOMING_CALL_ROUTE}")

        # Run the Flask app (no blocking loop, just event-based handling)
        app.run(port=PORT, debug=DEBUG)
    finally:
        # Always disconnect the ngrok tunnel
        ngrok.disconnect()


I’ve tried to listen for changes in the dynamic message and update it during the call by sending the updated message through WebSockets, but it doesn’t seem to trigger a new message to be sent to the caller.
I think it should be possible by triggering the event of receiving a digit, as it is working by pressing them manually.
